# single-post type.php in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

hey i am making a photogallery in wordpress i created photogallery and videogallery category
and using the post of photogallery category inside category-gallery.php gallery is also a category the code is:

```
    <?php 
         query_posts('category_name=photogallery');
        if(have_posts()): 
          while ( have_posts()) : the_post();
            $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID),'gallery-image');
                   $item = '<div class="col-lg-4">
                       <div class="photogallery_main_single">
                         <a href="'.get_permalink( $id ).'">
                          <img src="'.$img[0].'" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                         </a>
                         <div class="gallery_content">
                            <h4><a href="'.get_permalink( $id ).'">'.get_the_title().'</a></h4>

                            <span>'.get_the_date().' '.get_the_time().'</span>
                         </div><!--gallery content-->
                       </div><!--photogallery main single-->
                    </div>';
                    echo $item;
                endwhile; endif; ?>
```

problem is the permalink not forward towards single-photogallery.php help me if there is any other way to do that then help out please

Comment: I think you can't use single-photogallery.php, you can use it if "photogallery" is custom post type not category.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a custom post type called photogallery then you could create a file inside your theme called single-photogallery.php. This template will then display all of your posts of type `photogallery`. However, if 'photogallery' isn't a custom post type (if it is a category, or taxonomy for example) then the single-photogallery.php template will do nothing.

Comment: it is a category so what should i do

Comment: Try `category-photogallery.php`

Comment: henry code still not working actually the link jump the page to single .php any other solution like conditional tag inside single.php thanks for help

Comment: Even though your posts are assigned to the photogallery category, they are still of type `post`. single.php is the template used for posts of type `post` which is why your link (generated by `get_permalink( $id )`) is taking you to single.php

Comment: henry i know that i want to jump the permalink of single post to the specific single-$cat.php page like we do for category-slug.php

Comment: henry i got solution i add this code in functions.php add_filter('single_template', create_function('$t', 'foreach( (array) get_the_category() as $cat ) { if ( file_exists(TEMPLATEPATH . "/single-{$cat->term_id}.php") ) return TEMPLATEPATH . "/single-{$cat->term_id}.php"; } return $t;' ));    now single-$id.php work

Comment: Glad you found a solution!